# Отправка сообщения после полученного номера телефона

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Как сделать отправку последующего сообщения после того как пользователь скинул свой контакт?

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="private_office")
async def private_office_handler(query: types.CallbackQuery):
    keyboard = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add(
        KeyboardButton(text="Отправить свой номер телефона", request_contact=True)
    )
    await bot.send_message(
        query.from_user.id,
        MESSAGES["send_contact"],
        reply_markup=keyboard,
        parse_mode="MarkdownV2",
    )


@dp.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
async def contact_handler(message: types.Message):
    contact = message.contact
    await create_user(message.from_user.id, contact.phone_number, 
                      message.from_user.first_name,
                      message.from_user.last_name, message.from_user.username)


@dp.message_handler()
async def contact_end(message: types.Message):
    kbrm = ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хорошо, я буду обращаться к вам '
                                        '[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789), '
                                        'давайте введем дату рождения. Так я буду знать когда поздравить вас'
                                        'с праздником.', reply_markup=kbrm, parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень просто, перенесите содержимое функции contact_end в функцию contact_handler:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=["contact"])
async def contact_handler(message: types.Message):
    contact = message.contact
    await create_user(message.from_user.id, contact.phone_number, 
                      message.from_user.first_name,
                      message.from_user.last_name, message.from_user.username)

    kbrm = ReplyKeyboardRemove()
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Хорошо, я буду обращаться к вам '
                                        '[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789), '
                                        'давайте введем дату рождения. Так я буду знать когда поздравить вас'
                                        'с праздником.', reply_markup=kbrm, parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
```

Comment: Как добавить в новые столбцы таблицы полученные из последующих callback_query_handler-ов данные пользователя?

Comment: Непонятна Ваша проблема, создайте отдельный вопрос, и объясните, что Вам нужно